# how to load a facebox when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a button named'Add Item' and a list.When i select a particular content on that list,and i click on the button 'Add Item',it has to show a facebox.and on that facebox,there should be a dropdownlist(The values of that dropdown will be loaded from database based on certain conditions). Pls help me to do this,,,thanks inadvance

here is my code..
in view:

```
<input type="button" id="add_folder" value="Add Item"  rel="facebox" style="display:block; float:left;"/> //for the button 'Add Item'

<input type="hidden" name="nodeval" id="nodeval" value="" />
```

//To get the code of selected collection

```
$('#tree1').tree({selectable: true});
$('#tree1').bind('tree.click',
    function(event) {
    $('#nodeval').val(event.node.id);$('#nodepval').val(event.node.parent.id);
    }
);
```

//add

```
$('#add_folder').click(function(){
nval = $('#nodeval').val();
if(nval){
$.get('http://localhost/xxxx/add_items',{ nodval:nval},function(data) { 
if(data == 0){
alert('Cannot Add Items');
}else{
alert(data);                                               
}        
});
}else{alert('Please select any item to add.');}
  });
```

In Controller,,

```
     function add_items()
        {

 $this->layout = 'ajax';
 $nodval = trim($_REQUEST['nodval']);
 if($nodval)
             {

here i loaded some values from database based on certain conditions .and that is set to a variable 'users'


}else{
           echo "0";
             }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not clear about a certain part of your question, what role is the list you selected playing in this scenario because from what you just said you selected and click "add item" so why select from the list then?

Comment: The list that i meant is a collection like for example America,India,Srilanka. When i select India and click on "add item",a facebox should come with a dropdownlist,the contents of that dropdownlist may be some states of India..the states are loaded from database.